# Как добавить предпросмотр изображения в админ панели ? ( Symfony 4.2 SonataAdmin )

Tags: php, twig, symfony4, symfony-form

**// Это Admin файл**

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
 {

  $listMapper->addIdentifier('name')
             ->add(
                   'image', 'null',   [
                   'label'    => 'Изображение:',
                   'template' => 'App:Admin:templates:index.html.twig',// Здесь не получается обратиться к twig файлу, не видит его можно сказать.
                   ]);
    }
```

**// Это twig файл**

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}

    {% if object.image != null %}

        <img src="{{ asset('App/public/uploads/images/' ~ object.image)}}" alt="" />

    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**Доп. бандлы не использовал, Media тоже не использовал.**

Изображение сохраняет, уникальность создает, все впорядке, но проблема с выводом его в админ панеле. Не получается загрузить twig файл по указанному пути. 
Пробовал прописывать путь по разному. Может была у кого подобная загвоздка.

Comment: В object.image  получаете название картинки?